# Nextflow on GCP - waiting on container error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, nextflow

I'm running a pipeline on using nextflow on google batch. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'PLANT:NLREXPRESS (All_Candidate_Soybean_Prots_Simplified_Sorted)'

Caused by:
  Process `PLANT:NLREXPRESS (All_Candidate_Soybean_Prots_Simplified_Sorted)` terminated with an error exit status (null)

Command executed:

  mkdir output
  nlrexpress.py \
        --input All_Candidate_Soybean_Prots_Simplified_Sorted.fasta \
        --outdir ./output \
        --module all

  mv output/*.short.output.txt ./

Command exit status:
  null

Command output:
  15/06/2023 15:36:31:  ############ NLRexpress started ############
  15/06/2023 15:36:31:  Input FASTA: All_Candidate_Soybean_Prots_Simplified_Sorted.fasta
  15/06/2023 15:36:31:  Checking FASTA file - started
  15/06/2023 15:36:31:  Checking FASTA file - done
  15/06/2023 15:36:31:  Running JackHMMER - started

Command error:
  time="2023-06-15T15:39:22Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: "

Work dir:
  gs://rb-rnaseq/workDir/6e/090e663de08b69ce6c9506dc4975c1

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
```

The module nf file is here:

```
process NLREXPRESS {
  tag "$sample_id"
  maxForks 1
  container = 'dthorbur1990/nlrexpress:latest'

  cpus { 4 * task.attempt }
  memory { 12.GB * task.attempt }
  disk "15.GB"

  publishDir(
    path: "${params.PlantDir}",
    mode: 'copy',
  )
  
  input:
      tuple val(sample_id), path(peptides)

  output:
      path "*.short.output.txt", emit: nlre_out

  script:
  """
  mkdir output
  nlrexpress.py \\
        --input ${peptides} \\
        --outdir ./output \\
        --module ${params.NE_Modules}

  mv output/*.short.output.txt ./
  """
}
```

The process was running without error when I ran it locally, and I have rebuilt the container and it works as intended.

What confuses me is that the `workDir` doesn't contain either `.command.{out,err}` files suggesting (to me at least) that it's not running. But the Command output section of the error message is the correct first few lines of the tool.

Here is the workDir:

```
gsutil ls gs://rb-rnaseq/workDir/6e/090e663de08b69ce6c9506dc4975c1
gs://rb-rnaseq/workDir/6e/090e663de08b69ce6c9506dc4975c1/.command.begin
gs://rb-rnaseq/workDir/6e/090e663de08b69ce6c9506dc4975c1/.command.run
gs://rb-rnaseq/workDir/6e/090e663de08b69ce6c9506dc4975c1/.command.sh
```

And here is the end of the log file regarding the NLREXPRESS module:

```
All_Candidate_Soybean_Prots_Simplified_Sorted)","q3Label":"PLANT:NLREXPRESS (All_Candidate_Soybean_Prots_Simplified_Sorted)"},"writes":null},{"cpuUsage":null,"process":"ORIENTATION","mem":null,"memUsage":null,"timeUsage":null,"vmem":null,"reads":null,"cpu":null,"time":null,"writes":null}]
```

I'm at a loss. I've tried increasing memory but that hasn't seemed to have worked. Any ideas? Happy to add the `nextflow.log` file if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have an answer for you, but I think this behavior might have something to do with how Nextflow runs the job. If you look at the end of the `nxf_main` function in the `.command.run` script, you'll see something like:

```
nxf_main() {

    ...

    set +e
    ctmp=$(set +u; nxf_mktemp /dev/shm 2>/dev/null || nxf_mktemp $TMPDIR)
    local cout=$ctmp/.command.out; mkfifo $cout
    local cerr=$ctmp/.command.err; mkfifo $cerr
    tee .command.out < $cout &
    tee1=$!
    tee .command.err < $cerr >&2 &
    tee2=$!
    ( nxf_launch ) >$cout 2>$cerr &
    pid=$!
    wait $pid || nxf_main_ret=$?
    wait $tee1 $tee2
    nxf_unstage
}
```

When `errexit` is enabled (`set -e`), any command that returns a non-zero exit status immediately terminates the script. So by using `set +e`, we are explicitly disabling this behavior. This means that `.command.out` and `.command.err` may not necessarily be created despite the Docker container being run (via `nxf_launch`).

So I wonder if there is a problem with the size of `/dev/shm`? [Google Cloud Batch](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/google.html#cloud-batch) supports the [`containerOptions`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-containeroptions) directive<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/google.html#supported-directives)</sup>, so in the first instance, you might like to try bumping the shm-size<sup>[2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources)</sup> using something like this to your process definition:

```
process NLREXPRESS {

    container 'dthorbur1990/nlrexpress:latest'
    containerOptions '--shm-size 2g'

    ...
}
```

Note the typo when setting the `container` directive. Not sure if it will cause problems, but the `=` character should be avoided here. The assignment syntax using the `=` character is indeed required inside your `nextflow.config` for example.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though I'm still a little confused why it worked. The default shm-size is 64Mb, and the process runs fine locally where I also use the default nextflow settings. Though maybe the `nxf_main` `errexit` is set to `set +e` locally? I'll check next time. 

I couldn't find any mention of `errexit` in the nextflow docs. Is there a way of changing the Google Batch profile to not immediately quit on a non-zero exit? It seems like the `errorStrategy` parameter is more for dynamic retries than permitting specific error codes.

Comment: @dthorbur I think it's just due to differences in infrastructure. Google Cloud probably imposes a lower maximum limit for shared memory for one reason or another (optimization, stability, performance etc). If it runs fine with 64Mb, you might be able to get away with `--shm-size 128m` when running on GCC. The `containerOptions` directive can just be added to your Google Batch profile if you wish. With regards to this issue, I don't think anything else is needed here.